# Comma separated column values in a laravel join query

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a laravel webapp in which my database is structured via the below tables. The relationship is that `transactions hasmany loading_hire_agreements via lhas_transactions`.

```
Table name: transactions 
| id | date              | number |
|----|-------------------|--------|
| 1  | 12:00:00 00:00:00 | TRN#1  |
| 2  | 10:00:00 00:00:00 | TRN#2  |

Table name: loading_hire_agreements
| id | number |
|----|--------|
| 1  | JY1001 |
| 2  | JY1002 |
| 3  | JY1003 |

Table name: lhas_transactions
| transction_id | lha_id |
|---------------|--------|
| 1             | 1      |
| 1             | 2      |
| 2             | 3      |
```

I want to write a join statement using laravel's `DB:table()->join(\* any relevant join *\)` so that the below output is generated.

```
| transactions.id  | transactions.number | loading_hire_agreements.number |
|------------------|---------------------|--------------------------------|
| 1                | TRN#1               | JY1001, JY1002                 |
| 2                | TRN#2               | JY1003                         |
```

I "have" to use `DB:table()` because I am connecting this query to a front-end datatable service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `GROUP_CONCAT` and join all three tables:

```
$users = DB::table('transactions')
         ->join('lhas_transactions as lt', 'transactions.id', '=', 'lt.transaction_id')
         ->join('loading_hire_agreements as lha', 'lt.lha_id', '=', 'lha.id')
         ->select(DB::raw('transactions.id, transactions.number, GROUP_CONCAT(lha.number ORDER BY lha.id) AS agreements'))
         ->groupBy('transactions.id', 'transactions.number')
         ->get();
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks a lot for your answer. I have edited the question to add one more join. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Farveaz Nice.  I have reverted your question to the original, because it is rude to change the question substantially after other people have already answered.  Your "new" question would require twice the code of what I posted.  If you really have a need for that other query, then you should ask another question.

Comment: my apologies for the same. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question and reference this one.  I would have changed my answer, but you're going to need two separate subqueries, and that requires a bunch of really ugly Laravel code.